# Expo won't build to simulator instead of physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, expo

Expo for some reason has started giving me the following error when I try to build using "npx expo run:ios":

```
Your computer requires some additional setup before you can build onto physical iOS devices.
  Learn more
CommandError: No code signing certificates are available to use.
```

However, I have no intention of building for physical iOS devices, only for simulator. Googling this error, all the solutions talk about getting this to run on. a physical device, but this is not what I want - I want to go back to using a simulator.

I've been trying to deal with this issue for the past day as it has never shown this message before in the past; tried deleting my ios folder and looked in config and xcode settings for anything which might be relevant, as well as settings or additional commands but it keeps thinking I wish to build to a physical iOS device.

Also working with a new node_modules and pods folder and yarn.lock file.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me and I just had to open up my workspace in Xcode (`xed ios`) and configure `Team` with my code signing identity under `Signing & Capabilities` https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/setup-xcode-signing.md. It wasn't my app, so it showed some warnings like `Cannot create a iOS App Development provisioning profile for ...`, but I just ignored them and `expo run:ios` on the command line was happy

You might need to create a cert in Xcode first https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/sharing-your-teams-signing-certificates#Create-a-new-code-signing-identity

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding `usesAppleSignIn` to `app.json` and running `expo prebuild --clean` added an entitlement to the Xcode project, which produced this error.

Here are the two entitlements listed that will trigger this. https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/%40expo/cli/src/run/ios/codeSigning/simulatorCodeSigning.ts#L10

The issue was resolved when I removed `usesAppleSignIn` and then ran `expo prebuild --clean` again.

Comment: Unfortunately the error remains even after following these steps